# Give a programm an unconstrained amount of RAM

Tags: games, performance, ram, steam, system-monitor

I am running a Linux application, not WINE.

1. How can I find out if it has any memory constraints, if any at all?
2. If it does have memory constraints how can I increase it?

I have 12GB of system RAM. 
The process seems to be capping at 3.4GB of RAM. The name of the process is KSP.x86, it is a game.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "give it more RAM" exactly, as that's not how the system works. If the program is only using 3.4 GB of RAM, then that is all it needs to use. If it needs to use any more than that, it will try to use more. There is no need to try and force it to use more.

If it is a 32-bit application, it may not be able to use more.

Though, if it's using that much RAM, I would wonder why, as it really shouldn't need to.

Comment: I don't want to limit the amount of ram it can have.

Comment: @JebediahKerman Unless *you* limit it, it won't be limited, until you run out of RAM.

Comment: It's not limited, unless you specifically limited it. And if it was limited, the kernel would kill it, when that limit was exceeded. There is no need for a program to use all the memory you have available, on a multitasking general purpose computer system.